# Swiftui Button Toggle

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a series of buttons like this:

```
ForEach(context.items){item in
    Button(action: {
        self.variableSelection.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("\(item)")
        if self.variableSelection{
            Text("Extra text")
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

What is happening is:
A list of items appears and when I click a button the "Extra text" appears on the bottom of each button.

What I wanted to happen is for the "Extra text" to appear only below the button I clicked. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract row into separated view, so each row has own state of expanded/collapsed, like

```
struct ItemRowView: View {
  let item: String

  @State private var variableSelection = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.variableSelection.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("\(item)")
        if self.variableSelection{
            Text("Extra text")
        }
        
    }
  }
}
```

so now cycle

```
ForEach(context.items){item in
   ItemRowView(item: item)    
}
```